# Extract value of unnamed record from json in postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the data in json format in my postgres db as shown:

```
data={"id": "1:2:3", "[{\"info\": \"No\", \"links\": [\"<link rel": "''parent'' href=''http://example.com/1''/>\"], \"uid\": 1}]", "count": "9"}
```

In this json data, I have three different fields: `id`, `< unnamed field >` , `count`.

I got the logic to extract the named column data using this query:

```
select data->'count' as count from mydb;
```

Is there a way to get the 'uid' information from the unnamed field?

Comment: What do you mean "unnamed field?" Every value in a valid JSON object has a key string. That doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: @AndyCarlson by unnamed, i mean that the second part of this query itself consists of another json which has no name. It could have been like this:
data="{""id"": ""1:2:3"", ""mydata"": ""[{\""info\"": \""No\"", \""links\"": [\""http://example.com'/>\""], \""uid\"": 1}]"", ""count"": ""9""}"

 This is the data that I am getting from some server which I have saved in json format in my db.

Comment: What you're reffering to is a JSON array. Use the array index to access individual elements.
`data->'mydata'->0->>'uid'`

Comment: @AndyCarlson That would be valid for the case I gave in the comment. But, in my actual json, I don't have "mydata". It's in the form as shown above.

Comment: That is invalid JSON.

Comment: Can you show a working `insert` statement with which you insert this string in your table? Has the `data` column been created with the `json` (or `jsonb`) data type?

Comment: @trincot The data that is being saved is coming from some url using post request..

$.post('http://example.com?data=',data + '&id='+id + '&count='+count, "json"

On this server, I have the get request and saving data as acc_data::
 acc_data = request.get_json()
acc_data_json = json.dumps(acc_data)

After this is update query as :
"UPDATE mydb SET mydata = '%s' WHERE id = '%s';"%(acc_data_json, id).

data column is json

Comment: Then there must be a mistake in the string you provide in your question. Postgresql would give an error message if you would use that `update` statement with such a string. Can you please write out an example value for the variable *acc_data_json* for which you have verified that the `update` statement with that value works? It looks like you use Python, but the assignment statement to `data` you have provided in your question is not even valid for Python. Please provide an example that we can reproduce.

Comment: @trincot Updated the data query with the workable value in the question itself.
I have the update query as:
update mydb set data= '{"id": "1:2:3", "[{\"info\": \"No\", \"links\": [\"<link rel": "''parent'' href=''http://example.com/1''/>\"], \"uid\": 1}]", "count": "9"}' where id='2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your question update, the JSON you provide is valid:

```
{"id": "1:2:3", "[{\"info\": \"No\", \"links\": [\"<link rel": "''parent'' href=''http://example.com/1''/>\"], \"uid\": 1}]", "count": "9"}
```

...but it does not represent what you think it does. If you format that JSON in a more readable way, it looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "1:2:3", 
    "[{\"info\": \"No\", \"links\": [\"<link rel": 
         "''parent'' href=''http://example.com/1''/>\"], \"uid\": 1}]", 
    "count": "9"
}
```

So, note that the second entry in this object has (as required) a key and a value. I put the key and the corresponding value on a separate line to highlight this.

So, contrary to what you thought -- and what is very suggestive in that string --
that key's value is not a JSON string, but a broken part of it, while the first half of it serves as the key, which (with the escape characters resolved) is:

```
[{"info": "No", "links": ["<link rel
```

So the following SQL would work:

```
select mydata->'[{"info": "No", "links": ["<link rel' from mydb
```

... and would return this value:

```
"'parent' href='http://example.com/1'/>\"], \"uid\": 1}]"
```

Obviously this is not what you had hoped for, but it indicates that the JSON you have stored in your table is semantically wrong, even though technically it is valid JSON.

Object representations always have keys and values in JSON. Here is one of the ways the JSON could have had more sense:

```
{
    "id": "1:2:3", 
    "data": [{
        "info": "No", 
        "links": ["<link rel='parent' href='http://example.com/1'/>"],
        "uid": 1
    }], 
    "count": "9"
}
```

With this JSON in your table, you could do this SQL:

```
select (mydata->'data'->>0)::json->>'info' from mydb
```

...which would output:

```
No
```

But as you see, that JSON looks quite different. It is impossible to say where things went wrong with the information you have given. You should check what the JSON looks like when you get it from the service you are using. The error could be already there, but more probably you are processing this result in order to escape characters in preparation of writing the value to the database. It is probably in that manipulation that you break the semantics of that JSON.

#### After more info was provided

You call a service via URL parameters, like this:

```
$('#update').click(function(){ 
    $.post('example.com?data='+ data + '&id='+id + '&count='+count, 
        function callbackHandler(data, textstatus) {
            // some processing... 
        }, 
        "json" 
    ); 
});
```

But this way of passing arguments in a URL is not right, certainly not when `data` contains characters that have a special meaning in a URL. You should use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to build that URL:

```
    'example.com?data=' + encodeURIComponent(data)
               + '&id=' + encodeURIComponent(id)
               + '&count=' + count
```

As *count* is numerical, there is no need to apply `encodeURIComponent` to it, although it would not do any harm if you did.

Probably this will positively influence the data you get back from that server.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation. 
I am using this query to send the data. 
`
 $('#update').click(function(){
  $.post('http://example.com?data='+data + '&id='+id + '&count='+count,
      function callbackHandler(data, textstatus)
      {
   window.location="http://example.com/thanks";
       },
       "json"
      );
 });
`
But, in my response, I am getting the json as given above with two fields as id and count not data. I am not able to figure out why?

I believe that would solve the issue that I am running into. TIA.

Comment: Did you url-encode that `data` part in the URL? You cannot just put anything in a URL, you need to use a function like [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: Assuming you did not encode `data`, you may find a solution in the section I added to my answer.